# MySQL dump file with no schema

Tags: mysql

We have cancelled our subscription with ServiceNow who provided us with a db dump in a MySQL .sql file, but does not include any schema.  Is there any tools or tricks out there to extract the data out of this file?

Thanks,

Comment: *but does not include any schema* In MySQL the term "schema" is an alias of the term "database". Purify your task.

Comment: Do you mean the table structure like `SHOW CREATE TABLE {xxx}` statements? If so I'd use your backups, or ask ServiceNow for these too.

Comment: How was the database originally created - do you still have those scripts / instructions? If you still have access to the existing DB, "SHOW TABLES" will give you the list of tables, and "SHOW CREATE TABLE [table]" will give you the create statement for each [table] in that list (if you search on here you'll find scripts to do this, I have a hacked together PHP script that I adapted from someone else if you want me to post it). If you don't have either of these, you need to go back to ServiceNow and ask them to provide - reverse engineering from the data will miss details on keys, indexes, etc

Comment: The exact wording in their reply is "The error that you have received seems to occur as the DB dump does not include table statements (which means that we do not create schema). 

Please note that unfortunately, ServiceNow is not allowed to provide DB dump with schema, since it is part of our Intellectual Property. "